# How to write an ascii table using Astropy without the column names?

Tags: python-3.x, ascii, astropy

I construct a table using Astropy as follows: `data = astropy.table.Table(names=['Time', 'Rate (C/s)'])`. Then, I fill up the rows under the aforementioned columns using `data.add_row`. Finally, I intend to write the table in an ascii file. I do the following: `astropy.io.ascii.write(data, 'filename.dat')`. The output file contains the following:

```
Time "Rate (C/s)"
10.  25.65
20.  37.11
30.  15.10
```

However, I do not want the column names written in the first row as I will be using the file in another program that doesn't handle strings. My expected outcome is:

```
10.  25.65
20.  37.11
30.  15.10
```

How can I achieve the objective? I am expecting an answer using astropy only as I can do the needful using `numpy.savetxt`

Secondary question: In the output file, why is the second column name within quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
astropy.io.ascii.write(data, 'filename.dat', format="no_header")
```

You can find all the supported formats here: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/ascii/index.html#supported-formats

In the original output the second column name is in quotes because the format is "space-delimited" meaning that it uses a space character to separate the column names and column data. Without the quotes the parser would infer that there are three columns, `Time`, `Rate` and `(C/s)`.